# How to inspect Virtual Threads on a running JVM?

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, project-loom, virtual-threads

I have been using [Project Loom](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/going-inside-javas-project-loom-and-virtual-threads) to revive a game server - it's very old code that was written back when green threads were a thing, so writing a server on one-thread-per-connection model was not unreasonable - and it works quite well, in particular considering it's a preview feature.

*(I know, it's a preview feature, but this is a personal project and I'm happy to adjust if APIs change in the future - beats rewriting battle-tested code that already does its job well)*

On a traditional, thread-based app, I'd use the likes of [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) to inspect the running threads - but virtual threads being actually workloads, they won't show up there (I only see the thread pool that they share). I wonder if someone has already come up with a tool that allows one to inspect the virtual threads (e.g., to know precisely where they are blocked or whether they are running, how many of them are around, etc); it would help me a lot with debugging minor stuff.

Any advice?

Comment: It’s not a preview anymore. But I don’t know when VisualVM will catch up…

Comment: For now you can use `jcmd <pid> Thread.dump_to_file -format=json dump.json`

Comment: @GeorgeLeung that's a great idea! Sure, not as practical as VisualVM, but gives me a snapshot (and some inspiration for built-in monitoring until some GUI tool pops up). Thank you!

Comment: Let's hope they make it into VisualVM soon.